# how does prototype pattern create a deep copy throw clone() method

Tags: java, design-patterns, prototype-pattern

I know that `clone()` method create a shallow copy and prototype pattern create a deep copy but i don't know how prototype work to do it by still using `clone()` method. What is the core element to create a new object clone.

```
public interface Prototype {
    public abstract Object clone ( );
}



public class ConcretePrototype implements Prototype {
    public Object clone() {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

public class Client {

    public static void main( String arg[] ) 
    {
        ConcretePrototype obj1= new ConcretePrototype ();
        ConcretePrototype obj2 = ConcretePrototype)obj1.clone();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I donot think that prototype pattern is a deep copy always(depends on how you implement/override the clone() method).

**1**. It infact is a shallow copy if the class which overrides the
    clone method just calls the super.clone() as in your example above.

**2**. If the overridden method of clone() iterates through the fields
    of the actual object which we are cloning and try to create a new
    copy of those objects and store it in the object which we get out by
    calling super.clone() only then can it be called as a deep copy.

Until unless any class which implements the custom Prototype interface created and simple calls the super.clone() it would in turn be doing a shallow copy where in the parent and the cloned objects HAS A references of any external objects will both be pointing to same object and hence a shallow copy.

Also note that in the example that you provided you need to make your interface Prototype to implement Cloneable marker interface.